# jquery sortable floated elements with percent chaos

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-ui-sortable

After applying sortable to floated elements with percent based widths, dragging the last item of a row can "sometimes" cause the element to jump to the next row

This behaviour is only seen when the container is at particular widths... and thus has a random nature (mainly seen when applying sortable to responsive elements such as bootstrap styled columns)

See link below for a simple example... Dragging the orange box will highlight the issue:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ilawton/dhx6rwss/1/)

```js
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
});
```

```css
#sortable{
    width:239px;
}
#sortable div {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="sortable">
  <div style="background-color:red">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:blue">2</div>
  <div style="background-color:green">3</div>
  <div style="background-color:orange">4</div>
</div>
```

It appears to only be an issue when the container width divided by columns has .75 remainder. E.g. a container with a width of 239px and items with widths of 25% (239/4 = 59.75).

The browser deals with the above example, but sortable appears to apply a fixed width to the placeholder (or/and helper) and thus chaos ensues.

**I've submitted a bug with JQuery UI regarding this... But if anyone has any nice workarounds for the time being, I'd appreciate it.**

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify to helper, which is dragged while sorting:

```
 $("#sortable").sortable({
     helper: 'clone'
 });
```

So now the original `div` will be cloned for dragging, so jQuery don't need to create a new element, which obviously goes wrong.

Unfortunately I don't know if there are other sideeffects or edge-cases, but it will work for your provided example.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8e3gnp3/)

**Reference**

[.sortable() - helper](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper)